# Graph of scikit-learn ExtraTreeClassifier and RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, graph, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to make some graphs that illustrate the difference between RandomForestClassifier and ExtraTreeClassifier in scikit-learn. I think I might have figured it out but I am unsure.  Here is my code to fit and graph the iris dataset with both:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO 
from sklearn import tree
import pydot

iris = load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target

clf = tree.ExtraTreeClassifier()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)


dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data) 
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
file_name = "et_iris.pdf"
graph.write_pdf(file_name) 

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)


dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data) 
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
file_name = "rdf_iris.pdf"
graph.write_pdf(file_name)
```

The graphs that this produces seem correct, the ET graph is much "bushier" than the decision tree graph.

Am I correct that the DecisionTreeClassifier is the same as a single tree in a RandomForestClassifier and the ExtraTreeClassifier is the same as a single tree in an ExtraTreeClassifier?

Is there any way to do this with all the trees in an actual RDF or ET classifier? I tried using the .estimators_ in the forests but they do not have the export method it seems.

[image: Extra Tree Graph]

[image: RDF Graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`export_graphviz` is not a method, it is a function. None of the trees "has" it. You can use it with the `estimators_`.
You are right about `ExtraTreeClassifier` being a single tree in `ExtraTreesClassifier` and `DecisionTreeClassifier` being a single tree in `RandomForestClassifier`. However, that doesn't really cover it, because:

- `RandomForestClassifier` bootstraps the data set separately for each tree, `ExtraTreesClassifier` does not bootstrap (by default).
- `max_features=n_features` for single trees by default, that is all features can be used in every split.

Comment: So it looks like if I create a bootstrap sample for the DecisionTreeClassifier myself and feed in a subset of features it would be the equivalent.

Comment: Subsampling the features globally is not equivalent. But you can set max_features on the tree: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier (they get sampled separately for every split)

Comment: Thanks...I am getting what I wanted which is a comparison of how the different trees "look".